# Return value from asynchronous SQL method

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
- (NSString *)obtenerDatosUsuario
{
   __block NSString *result=@"";
    [self obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL:^(NSString *resultadoSQL){
        result=resultadoSQL;
    }];
    return result;
}
```

And I want that the return be the content of `resultadoSQL`

Comment: Does `-obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL:` run synchronously or asynchronously? In the second case, your `return` statement will run before the block is executed and hence `result` will not be set yet.

Comment: (It looks like it is asynchronous: otherwise it would simply return an `NSString` instead of accepting a block as an argument.)

Comment: What does this code has to do with swift?

Comment: The method is asynchronously, but exist any form to get the value in return? @NicolasMiari

Comment: Because I get the result in Swift. @Sulthan

Comment: No; not in the return. You can't take an asynchronous method and turn it synchronous. It is hard to say what your best option is without seeing more of your code.

Comment: You need to rendez-vous with the asynchronous method somehow. Impossible to recommend something since I do not know where and how you will use `result`.

Comment: The code is simple I execute one SQL query and I want get the result in Swift and I use that method to get the result and send in a return. @NicolasMiari

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct about what happens inside your method `-obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL:` (i.e., it performs a lengthy operation in a background thread, and gives the result to the passed block argument), then your code runs in the following order:

1. You call `-obtenerDatosUsuario`
2. You call `-obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL:`, passing a **completion handler** block.
3. Execution proceeds forward and reaches the `return` statement at the end of `-obtenerDatosUsuario`, and exits the method body. **The returned variable `result` hasn't been set yet!**
4. Sometime later, the SQL query completes and the block is executed. But it is too late to return the result because execution already exited the method `-obtenerDatosUsuario`.

Comment: Exist one way to give back the content of variable called resultadoSQL in the return?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make this asynchronous method behave synchronously (e.g. semaphores), but it generally is a very, very bad idea. Most likely, `obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL` is asynchronous because there is a chance (even if only a small chance) that the result won't be returned immediately. Maybe it's possible that the SQL will be slow. Or maybe you'll eventually be doing queries from multiple threads, so this query might have to wait for queries in other threads to finish. Or there might be other reasons. But whatever the reason, this method was implemented as asynchronous method, and you should embrace that, rather than fight it. If you change `obtenerDatosUsuario` to return synchronously, you open yourself to a wide variety of possible problems.

Instead, you should just adopt asynchronous pattern in your code. For example, let's imagine that you have some code that was planning on using the result of `obtenerDatosUsuario` for some other purpose, e.g.:

```
NSString *resultadoSQL = [self obtenerDatosUsuario];
// use `resultadoSQL` here
```

Just change that to:

```
[self obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL:^(NSString *resultadoSQL){
    // use `resultadoSQL` here
}];
// but not here
```

And, if you're using `obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL` in some method that you're currently trying to return the value immediately, then change that to behave asynchronously, too. For example, let's assume you had something like:

```
- (NSString *)someOtherMethod {
    NSString *resultadoSQL = [self obtenerDatosUsuario];

    // let's assume you're doing something else with `resultadoSQL` to build some other string

    NSString *string = ...  // some expression using `resultadoSQL`
    return string;
}
```

Then, you'd change that to also adopt asynchronous pattern:

```
- (void)someOtherMethod:(void (^)(NSString *))completionHandler {
    [self obtenerDatosUsuarioSQL:^(NSString *resultadoSQL){
        NSString *string = ...  // some expression using `resultadoSQL`
        completionHandler(resultadoSQL);
    }];
}
```

When you first encounter this, this may seem unnecessarily complicated, but asynchronous programming is so critical, such a fundamental part of Cocoa programming, that one really must gain some familiarity with these common asynchronous patterns, such as blocks. Personally, we use block syntax so much that I [create code snippets](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/) in Xcode's "Code Snippet Library" for [typical block patterns](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/), which simplifies life a lot and gets you out of the world of memorizing the unintuitive block syntax.

But don't be tempted to wrap asynchronous method in another method that makes it behave synchronously. You open yourself up to many types of problems if you do that.